# Face Detection in Preview Camera Feed on Flutter

Tags: flutter, opencv, flutter-dependencies

How do we "draw a square" on detected faces on camera preview feed in Flutter? Is there a cross platform solution to this?

Flutter provides a [Camera Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/camera), but is there a way for us to draw a square box detecting faces on the **preview feed**? Any thoughts on this please?

.

**SOMETHING LIKE THIS EXAMPLE CAMERA PREVIEW FEED**

[image: Something like this]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, get the image data. This can be done by either using the `camera` plugin's output, or even directly communicate with the SurfaceView/TextureView.

Secondly, run face detection algorithm. If you do not need cross-platform, https://medium.flutterdevs.com/face-detection-in-flutter-2af14455b90d?gi=f5ead7c6d7c9 MLKit sounds good. If needing cross-platform, you can use Rust algorithms like https://github.com/atomashpolskiy/rustface and bind Rust code to Flutter via https://github.com/fzyzcjy/flutter_rust_bridge. Or, use C++ face detection algorithms and bind to Flutter (though setup may be a bit harder).

Lastly, once you know the face, draw a box around it. For example, `Container` widget.

Comment: is Rustface an offline implementation? What about Tensorflow in this scenario?

Comment: Sure, it is. Also you can use tensorflow's models, just remember to use `tflite-rust` ( I use that personally and it works great).